# MVC 5 Viewmodel binding works but post back is partial filled

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a parameterless `Index` for the `HttpGet` which works. But when I post it the `HttpPost` version of `Index` is invoked and the viewmodel object is passed in, but there is only the value of the dropdown in it. The rest is null (products, title)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ProductsViewModel pvm)
{
    // breakpoint on line 36, shows that pvm.Title is null and Products too.
    return View(pvm);
}
```

My compilable and running example can be downloaded from my OneDrive http://1drv.ms/1zSsMkr

My view:

```
@model KleinKloteProductOverzicht.Models.ProductsViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Products"))
{
<h2>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Title)</h2>
<input type="submit" value="post dit" /><br/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CurrentSort, EnumHelper.GetSelectList(typeof(SortOptions)), new { @class = "multiselect"})
    </div>
</div>
if (Model.Products.Count() > 0)
{
    <div class="row">
        @foreach (var item in Model.Products)
        {
            @Html.DisplayFor(i => item.Name);
        }
    </div>
}
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code from the relevant part of the view ? What does the form data contain when you post it ?

Comment: you need to show you relevant view code

Comment: Nobody will bother to download the code...

Comment: It has to be set in your view to be posted back. For instance if you have a selectlist filled on from the action and sent to the view, it will be null when it is posted back because the property doesn't get set from the view!

Comment: lol, it seems that uploading a test project to onedrive is useless ;) will update the question with my razor view

Comment: But I'd like to sort them when I post back and do not feel like retrieving all the products again. saves me a database query.

Comment: For `Products` you not generating any controls that will post back anything (and you would need to use a `for` loop or custom `EditorTemplate` for typeof `Product` if you did)

Comment: try with for loop, and index the items : `item[i].Name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have this view model:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string SelectedLocation {get;set;}

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Locations {get;set;}
}
```

And your actions look like this:

```
public ActionResult MyForm()
{
    var vm = new ViewModel
    {
        Locations = context.Locations.ToList() // Some database call
    }

    return View(vm);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyForm(ViewModel vm)
{
    vm.Locations // this is null
}
```

It is `null` because the model binder can't find a form control that is setting its data.

The `<form>` must set some data in the view for the model binder to pick it up.

```
<form>
    Name: <input type="text" id="name" />
</form>
```

This will set the `Name` property on the view model, because the model bind can see the `id` of the form control and uses that to know what to bind to.

So in terms of your view, you need to make sure you wrap any content that you want to post back to the server with `@using(Html.BeginForm())`

Anyway this is my guess.

Comment: So how should I adjust my view to make sure that Model.Products is not null (same for title)

Comment: updated my answer, have a look at [asp.net](http://asp.net) as well because they show you how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you seem to be confused as to how [HttpPost] and form tags interact with eachother.

You see, when .NET MVC binds your parameters in your controller actions, it tries to derive that data from the request. For [HttpGet] it does this by looking at the query string.

For [HttpPost] calls, it also looks at the Request.Form. This variable is populated with the values of all input fields that were inside the form you submitted.

Now, this is your view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Products"))
{
    <h2>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Title)</h2>
    <input type="submit" value="post dit" /><br/>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CurrentSort, EnumHelper.GetSelectList(typeof(SortOptions)), new { @class = "multiselect" })
        </div>
    </div>
    if (Model.Products.Count() > 0)
    {
        <div class="row">
            @foreach (var item in Model.Products)
            {
                @Html.DisplayFor(i => item.Name);
            }
        </div>
    }
}
```

You only have one `select` tag (generated by Dropdownlistfor) but no other inputs. That's why .NET MVC cannot infer any other data for your view model.

If you change your view to this:

```
@model KleinKloteProductOverzicht.Models.ProductsViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Products"))
{
    <h2>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Title)</h2>
    <input type="submit" value="post dit" /><br/>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CurrentSort, EnumHelper.GetSelectList(typeof(SortOptions)), new { @class = "multiselect" })
        </div>
    </div>
    if (Model.Products.Count() > 0)
    {
        <div class="row">
            @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Products.Count; i++)
            {
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Products[i].Name)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Products[i].ID)
            }
        </div>
    }

}
```

You'll see I've added a hidden input (`<input type="hidden">`) for the product id. Note that the product name still will be null.

I would suggest you follow a tutorial on .NET MVC and read up on some of the concepts behind it, because the very fact that you ask this question reveals that you have much to learn.

Best of luck!

P.S. One last tip: `@Html.Blablabla` writes directly to your view. You usually don't need that ";" at the end, because it will be inside your generated html.

Answer (score 0):

Your property is not associated with a "postable" control, therefore it will not be submitted along with the form data. If your really want to get the value in your `Title` property, just set it as a hidden input.

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Title)
```

A `label` will not be posted when submitting a `form` but an `input` will. This is exactly what `HiddenFor` does; it creates a hidden `input` element which will be picked up by the `form` submit.